# Как переопределить присваивание в данном случае?

Tags: c++, итераторы

Есть класс:

```
class Aircraft
{
public:
    /* СДЕЛАТЬ КОНСТРУКТОР */

    //  Name of an aircraft
    std::string aircraftName;

    //  Number of a flow
    int flowNumber;

    //  Enter time in a flow
    double arrivingTime;

    //  Whether an aircraft was delayed or not?
    bool delayFlag;

    //  Arriving time after delay
    double arrivingTime_Delayed;

    //  Constructor for the class
    Aircraft (std::string _aircraftName, int _flowNumber, double _enterTime, bool _delayFlag, double _arrivingTime_Delayed);

    //  Generates a new aircraft in a random flow
    static Aircraft genNextAircraft(double _arrivingTimeLA, int _flowQuantity);

    //  Getting info abount an aircraft
    void getInfo() const;

};
```

Объекты данного класса после создания кладу в vector:

```
vector<Aircraft> aircrafts;

//  Generating requirement amount of aircrafts
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aircraftQuantity; counter++) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            //  The firts aircraft gets arrival time from [0, 600] sec
            Aircraft newAircraft = Aircraft::genNextAircraft(0, flowQuantity);
            aircrafts.push_back(newAircraft);
        } else {
            Aircraft lastAircraft = *(aircrafts.end()--);
            Aircraft newAircraft = Aircraft::genNextAircraft(lastAircraft.arrivingTime, flowQuantity);
            aircrafts.push_back(newAircraft);
        }
    }
```

Поле arrivingTime у нового объекта генерируется на основе значения этого же поля у предыдущего сгенерированного объекта. Чтобы его получить, создаю ссылку на последний в векторе объект. Затем в конструкторе для нового объекта уже беру значение в поле предыдущего объекта.

Дебаг показал, что в это строке

```
Aircraft lastAircraft = *(aircrafts.end()--);
```

прилетает мусор. Скорее всего, происходят непонятки с оператором = для сложных объектов. Как его переопределить? Нашел варианты с хабра и других ресурсов, однако не работает.

Comment: Может лучше использовать aircrafts.back(), чтобы получить значение последнего элемента? Попробуйте воспользоваться банальным Aircraft lastAircraft = aircrafts.back();

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с тем, что такое [mcve] и постарайтесь описывать вопрос именно в таком виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(aircrafts.end()--);
```

Итак, что делается...
Получаем итератор, который указывает **за конец** вектора. Выполняем постфиксный `--`, который возвращает значение до декремента, и разыменовываем его. Т.е. пытаемся получить значение **за концом** вектора.

Вряд ли там лежит что-то умное...

Попробуйте *сначала* выполнить декремент:

```
*(--aircrafts.end());
```

Хотя логичнее получить из вектора последнее значение с помощью специально для этого созданной функции `back()`. Только нужно сначала убедиться, что вектор не пуст.

Comment: Ну почему же? aircrafts.end() – невалидный итератор, расположенный после последнего элемента. И он должен указывать на конец контейнера.
К данному моменту в векторе уже лежит хотя бы один элемент. И декрементация должна на него указывать. Если не так, поправьте?

Comment: Он указывает на конец в том смысле, что **за последний элемент**. Если их 5 - значит, на шестой. **Постфиксный** декремент возвращает значение **до** декремента. Вы его и разыменовываете.